# Yii - Widgets - Explanation

Tags: yii

I am trying to use drop down list widget :

```
  $this->widget('ext.multiselect.JMultiSelect',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'attribute'=>'attribute',
      'data'=>$data,
      // additional javascript options for the MultiSelect plugin
      'options'=>array()
));
```

What I want to know is that Details of each option available in the widget array Like what is 'attribute' , 'model' and'data' represent , as I an unable to understand it form the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `model` param is the model you are creating the multi select for.

The `attribute` is the model attribute you are creating the multi select for.

The `data` is an array of key/value pairs for the list items you want to display in the multi select.

For example, if you had a model 'User' and in that model you had a field 'access_rights' and you wanted to have that field as a multi select box with a few values, you might do something like:

In your controller:

```
$model = new User;

$data = array(
    'admin_area'=>'Admin Area Access',
    'product_area'=>'Product Area Access',
    'customer_area'=>'Customer Area Access',
    ... etc
);
```

In your form in your view file:

```
$this->widget('ext.multiselect.JMultiSelect',array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'access_rights',
    'data'=>$data,
    // additional javascript options for the MultiSelect plugin
    'options'=>array()
));
```

Edit:

To add data to the multi select options from another model you can use the [CHtml::listData()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) method, this takes an active record result set and converts it into an array of key/value pairs so you can use in any of the other CHtml methods that require a key/value pair. To do this you simply get the records you're after from the database using active record, eg;

```
$myData = Data::model->findAll();
```

You can then put that into the listData() method and it'll create your array:

```
$this->widget('ext.multiselect.JMultiSelect',array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'access_rights',
    'data'=>CHtml::listData($myData, 'id', 'name'),
    // additional javascript options for the MultiSelect plugin
    'options'=>array()
));
```

(where 'id' and 'name' are the fields from the model table that you want to be the 'key' and 'value' within the array)

Comment: What if I want to add data from database in $data ?

Comment: For that you can use CHtml::listData(), I've updated my answer to include some info on that for you.

Comment: I have done this . Now I am getting error in extension call :

Alias "ext.multiSelect.JMultiSelect" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file.

Comment: 318                         throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','Alias "{alias}" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file.',array('{alias}'=>$alias)));

Comment: were you not getting this error before? that's a bit odd, have you changed where any of the files are located?

Comment: I was getting this error before ,, Anyways I have did this work with an easy method , check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'category', CHtml::listData(TblCategory::model()->findAll(),
                'id', 'category_name'), array('empty' => '---Select Category---', 
                     'style' => 'width:350px;')), array() ?>

        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'category'); ?>
```